# How to correctly sort a multi-indexed pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi-indexed pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
Antibody                 Time Repeats           
Akt                      0    1         1.988053
                              2         1.855905
                              3         1.416557
                         5    1         1.143599
                              2         1.151358
                              3         1.272172
                         10   1         1.765615
                              2         1.779330
                              3         1.752246
                         20   1         1.685807
                              2         1.688354
                              3         1.614013
                         .....        ....
                         0    4         2.111466
                              5         1.933589
                              6         1.336527
                         5    4         2.006936
                              5         2.040884
                              6         1.430818
                         10   4         1.398334
                              5         1.594028
                              6         1.684037
                         20   4         1.529750
                              5         1.721385
                              6         1.608393
```

(Note that I've only posted one `antibody`, there are many analogous entries under the `antibody` index) but they all have the same format. Despite missing out the entries in the middle for the sake of space you can see that I have 6 experimental repeats but they are not organized properly. My question is: how would I get the DataFrame to aggregate all the repeats. So the output would look something like this:

```
Antibody                 Time Repeats           
Akt                      0    1         1.988053
                              2         1.855905
                              3         1.416557
                              4         2.111466
                              5         1.933589
                              6         1.336527
                         5    1         1.143599
                              2         1.151358
                              3         1.272172
                              4         2.006936
                              5         2.040884
                              6         1.430818
                         10   1         1.765615
                              2         1.779330
                              3         1.752246
                              4         1.398334
                              5         1.594028
                              6         1.684037
                         20   1         1.685807
                              2         1.688354
                              3         1.614013
                              4         1.529750
                              5         1.721385
                              6         1.60839
                         .....        ....
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you try `df.sort_index(level=[0,1])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.sort_index(level=[0,1,2])
print (df)
Antibody  Time  Repeats
Akt       0     1          1.988053
                2          1.855905
                3          1.416557
                4          2.111466
                5          1.933589
                6          1.336527
          5     1          1.143599
                2          1.151358
                3          1.272172
                4          2.006936
                5          2.040884
                6          1.430818
          10    1          1.765615
                2          1.779330
                3          1.752246
                4          1.398334
                5          1.594028
                6          1.684037
          20    1          1.685807
                2          1.688354
                3          1.614013
                4          1.529750
                5          1.721385
                6          1.608393
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Or you can omit parameter `levels`:

```
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
Antibody  Time  Repeats
Akt       0     1          1.988053
                2          1.855905
                3          1.416557
                4          2.111466
                5          1.933589
                6          1.336527
          5     1          1.143599
                2          1.151358
                3          1.272172
                4          2.006936
                5          2.040884
                6          1.430818
          10    1          1.765615
                2          1.779330
                3          1.752246
                4          1.398334
                5          1.594028
                6          1.684037
          20    1          1.685807
                2          1.688354
                3          1.614013
                4          1.529750
                5          1.721385
                6          1.608393
Name: col, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, thanks for the response. This was my approach too but for me I get a split on level 0. So the first three repeats are at the top of the df and the second three in the middle

Comment: How does work sort only for second and third level? `df = df.sort_index(level=[1,2])`

Comment: I've just realized that my problem was with not having `inplace=True` so I was just returning the old frame. This is working now. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, or assign or `inplace` is neccesary.

Comment: Glad can help you!